# Show that the set all two-element subsets of R is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the easiest way to show that the set of all two-element-subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable?

It's simple enough to show a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to the singleton sets by $f(x)=\{x\}$, but what about the two-element-sets? It's probably extremely simple, but I just can't see it. Thanks

Comment: I thought about it, but is $\{x,x\}$ a valid set? It contains two copies of the same element?

Comment: @user274604 $\{x,x\}$ is a perfectly fine set. So is $\{x,x,x\}$. However they are equal to the singleton set $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f$ that maps all two element subset of $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathbb{R}$
$$f(\{x,y\})=x$$
is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Let $[\Bbb R]^2$ be the family of all two-element subsets of $\Bbb R$. Consider the map

$$\varphi:\Bbb R\to[\Bbb R]^2:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\{0,x\},&\text{if }x\ne 0\\
\{1,2\},&\text{if }x=0\;.
\end{cases}$$